# Automated Tools for Traditional Chinese Subtitles

Tags: traditional-characters, technology

What is the easiest way to transcribe subtitles in traditional Chinese for videos? Likewise, what about an easy way to synchronize traditional Chinese subtitles and include the subtitles as hardsubs in the video? I am looking for automated tools here. How do you deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the Subtitles?

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I had the same need, so I came up with a solution.

https://github.com/hamsolo474/VideoSubFinder_ocr_path

You will need some basic programming skills to get it working, but if you don't find any other solutions then this is probably your best bet.